# Automatically power on laptop when plugged in

Tags: power-management

The power settings allows me to let the laptop shutdown when there's not enough battery, is there way to configure the opposite so that it'll boot up when there's power?

Comment: That would be possible if hardware and BIOS/UEFI-firmware support such a feature. Then it would be possible to configure in BIOS/UEFI-settings, not in the OS. I've never seen such a feature though...

Comment: @mook765, I know some desktops had the option to do that, but I hoped somehow OS-land could achieve it too... :(

Comment: OS is not running when the computer is shut down, so how could the OS recognize if power state changes? Impossible!

Comment: @mook765 You're probably are talking about Wake On Lan, WOL, that let's you boot a system.

Comment: Interesting question and: **Yes that's possible** as my Thinkpad T460s from work has such a feature: When you plug it in, it boots without pushing the power button, regardless of the battery state.  

However, my private laptop does not have that feature so I'll be comparing the UEFI firmware on both this week-end when I have more time.  Leave a comment @Fabby if I should pursue this, otherwise I'll probably forget...  *If you have a BIOS-based machine, you're automatically out of luck unless you find a BIOS programmer.*

Comment: @Fabby, I missed the weekend you mentioned because I don't remember receiving email notif of your comment, but it doesn't matter because the laptop in context is BIOS-based. But I'm still interested in the UEFI solution you seem to have.

Comment: I don't have a UEFI solution: I had a look and the Thinkpad seems to have 2 power buttons in hardware, so I'm *guessing* the second one is the "when plugged in", so your problem is unsolvable purely using software only.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this needs a hardware solution.  (See comment above this one)

Comment: Well, that sucks.